# while doing "query": { "match_all" : {} } i get less number of records than the total in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

There are in total 1000000 records, but when i execute the below query it shows only 10,000

```
GET /Index_Here/_search
{
  
  "query": { "match_all" : {} }
}
```

I have added the below size also still it does not work

```
GET /Index_Here/_search
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 20000,
  "query": { "match_all" : {} }
}
```

even i have updated the max windows size also

```
PUT /Index_Here/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "max_result_window": 200000
  }
}
```

Comment: is the result being paginated?

Comment: @ti7 what does it mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

This is a default in elasticsearch, to offer a [good trade of between performance and accuracy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits).

## Solution

You may disregard this "optimisation" by using the param `track_total_hit`.

```json
GET /Index_Here/_search
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": { "match_all" : {} }
}
```